# Contour Integral of Geometric Series

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, contour-integration, distribution-theory

I'm uncertain about the subtleties of the following contour integration, so maybe somebody can tell me what is precisely going on.

First consider the function
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} \qquad |z|<1 \tag{1}
$$
which converges for $|z|<1$. As far as I'm aware it even converges for $|z|=1$ as long as $z\neq 1$. Now integrate over the circle of radius $R<1$
$$
\oint_{|z|=R} f(z) \, {\rm d}z \, .
$$
The pole of the RHS of ${\rm (1)}$ is not enclosed, and thus the integral is zero. Indeed the LHS gives
$$
\oint_{|z|=R} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \, {\rm d}z \stackrel{R<1}{=} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \oint_{|z|=R} z^{n} \, {\rm d}z
$$
but
$$
\oint_{|z|=R} z^{n} \, {\rm d}z = 2\pi i \, R^{n+1} \, \delta_{n,-1} \tag{2}
$$
so every term of the series is zero as expected.
Now what does happen if $R=1$ ? Is everything still allowed as long as I miss the pole at $z=1$ by $\epsilon>0$ (integration from $1+\epsilon$ to $1-\epsilon$) ?

I'm asking, because now consider the following function
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n \qquad |z|=1,z\neq 1 \tag{3}
$$
which should converge for $|z|=1,z\neq 1$. If I would like to assign some function to the RHS of ${\rm (3)}$ it would be something like $2\pi i \, \delta(z-1)$. Again integration over $|z|=R$ gives
$$
\oint_{|z|=R} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n \, {\rm d}z \stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \oint_{|z|=R} z^{n} \, {\rm d}z
$$
where I presume the only allowed value for interchanging the order of summation would be $R=1$. Then by ${\rm (2)}$ the term $n=-1$ is covered and yields $2\pi i$.
But if $R=1$ is allowed, then why is it not possible to obtain the same result with the function $f(z)$ using the series?

If $F(z)$ is a holomorphic function, then the way I interpret this is
\begin{align}
\int_{a^+}^{b^+} F(z) \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n \,  {\rm d}z &= \int_{a^+}^{b^+}\frac{F(z)}{1-z} \, {\rm d}z + \int_{a^-}^{b^-} \frac{F(z)}{z-1} \, {\rm d}z \\
&=\int_{b^+}^{a^+}\frac{F(z)}{z-1} \, {\rm d}z + \int_{a^-}^{b^-} \frac{F(z)}{z-1} \, {\rm d}z \\
&= \oint_{b^+}^{b^-}\frac{F(z)}{z-1} \, {\rm d}z \\
&= 2\pi i \, F(1)
\end{align}
with $a<1<b$.

Comment: Your statement that "it even converges  for $|z|$=1 as long as $z \neq 1$" is not true. For the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ to converge you must at the very least have $\lim_{n\to \infty}z^n=0$.

Comment: True, but why does everything still seem to work for $g(z)$ ?
The series does not seem to converge for any $z$ then...

Comment: I don't understand why do you think that you are able to switch the sum with the integral here. It's known that you can switch Laurent series with integral in the domain (which is usually an annulus) where the series converge. But you need convergence for that.

Comment: Yes, still the entire thing seems to make sense in a distributional way, so I wonder what the back-ground for that is? I mean aren't we even agreeing about the result?

Comment: I'm sorry but how do you come across the $\zeta$-function now? I'm talking about distributions...

Comment: @clayton $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^s}$ does not converge for $|s|=1$ and $s\neq 1$.

Comment: The series which is convergent for $|z|=1$ and $z\neq 1$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}n$.